# Cannot extract number from string in python with split() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I looked online and every method for extracting numbers from strings uses the 
`[int(word) for word in a_string.split() if word.isdigit()]`  method, 
however when I run the code below, it does not extract the number `45`

```
test = "ON45"
print(test)
print([int(i) for i in test.split() if i.isdigit()])
```

This is what python prints

```
ON45
[]
```

The second list is empty, it should be `[45]` which I should be able to access as integer using `output_int = test[0]`

Comment: @busybear not a good dup because it also uses `split` but the way iit was supposed to be...

Answer (score 1):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments splits a string on whitespace, which your string has none of. Thus you end up with `i` in your list comprehension being `ON45` which does not pass `isdigit()`; hence your output list is empty. One way of achieving what you want is:

```
int(''.join(i for i in test if i.isdigit()))
```

Output:

```
45
```

You can put that in a list if desired by simply enclosing the `int` in `[]` i.e.

```
[int(''.join(i for i in test if i.isdigit()))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works:

```
import re
test = "ON45"
print(test)
print(str(list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', test)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the individual digits

```
print([int(i) for i in test if i.isdigit()])
```

output 
   `[4, 5`]

If you want to get concatenated numbers

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', test))
```

output
    `['45']`

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the characters in each string from the list resulting from the split, filter out the non-digit characters, and then join the rest back into a string:

```
test = "ON45"
print([int(''.join(i for i in s if i.isdigit())) for s in test.split()])
```

This outputs:

```
[45]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `string.split()` splits on space, which you don't have in the original string. With the string `"ON 24"` it'd work just fine.